# Put a Win 7 computer to sleep AND wake it up on schedule

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate, windows-task-scheduler

The computer in our bedroom puts on a light show every night around 3 when it starts to update Windows.   I'd like to put the PC to sleep at a fixed time and then have it wake up on its own at a later time.

I've seen plenty of ways here to make it go to sleep (hibernate?) here.  However, I haven't seen a way to make it do both.

Comment: Did you tried [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/)

Comment: [first hit on google](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/schedule-wake-sleep-windows-automatically/)

Comment: I guess the issue is the light? Why not turn off the monitor?

Comment: @DaveRook I'm pretty sure he means the HDD and Power led. They will brighten up a dark room, especially at midnight.

Comment: Create a wake-up task that runs a do-nothing batch file you've created at the desired time and select task-scheduler options to wake the computer if it's asleep to perform that task.